# Socket Programming with Dynamic IP

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client

I have client and server files in c#. In client file, the program connects to server with a static ip like 192.168.1.200. But I want to connect dynamic ip from client. So, the client will search my server and find it and connect it. For example when I try to find ip on wifi, I can't find any ip. Also how can I find ip addresses on wifi with wireless .My code is below.

Server Side Code

```
 public partial class ServerForm : Form
  {
    private static readonly List<String> clientSockets = new List<String>();
    private static readonly List<Socket> clientim = new List<Socket>();
    private static readonly Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    public static Thread connectionThread;
    private int cıkıs;
    Socket listener;

    public ServerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecuteServer));
        thr.IsBackground = true;
        thr.Start();
    }

    private static void ExecuteServer() //server baglantısı olusturuyor
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[1];
        //IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(ipAdresi);
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 1996);
        Console.WriteLine("Server ip address: " + ipAddr);

        try
        {

            serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);

            serverSocket.Listen(10);

            while (true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Waiting connection ... ");

                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
                clientim.Add(clientSocket);

                byte[] bytes = new Byte[2048];
                string data = null;

                while (true)
                {

                    int numByte = clientSocket.Receive(bytes);

                    data += Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes,
                                               0, numByte);

                    if (data.IndexOf("192.168.1") > -1)
                    {

                        break;
                    }

                }
                clientSockets.Add(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Text received -> {0} ", data);
                byte[] message = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("Server");

                clientSocket.Send(message);

            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    //when click the button, send message to client
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        devices_battery_midlow_pic_1.Visible = false;
        devices_battery_low_pic_1.Visible = true;
        devices_battery_midhigh_pic_1.Visible = false;
        devices_battery_high_pic_1.Visible = false;

        String video = "DENEME";//select_video_comboBox.Text;

        foreach (String Ips in clientSockets)
        {
            //byte[] data = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("dd");
            //int bytesent = socket.Send(data);
            Console.WriteLine(Ips);
            //byte[] message = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("Server");
            //listener.Send(message);
        }

        send();


    }
```

Client Side Code

```
class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        ExecuteClient(); 
    } 

    // ExecuteClient() Method 
    static void ExecuteClient() 
    { 

        try { 

            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()); 
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[1]; 

            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), 1996); 

            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, 
                       SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 

            try { 

                 sender.Connect(localEndPoint); 

                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to -> {0} ", 
                              sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()); 

                byte[] messageSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ipAddr.ToString()); 
                int byteSent = sender.Send(messageSent); 

                byte[] messageReceived = new byte[1024]; 


                int byteRecv = sender.Receive(messageReceived); 
                Console.WriteLine("Message from Server -> {0}",  
                      Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageReceived,  
                                                 0, byteRecv)); 

                // Close Socket using  
                // the method Close() 
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both); 
                sender.Close(); 
            } 

            // Manage of Socket's Exceptions 
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane) { 

                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString()); 
            } 

            catch (SocketException se) { 

                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString()); 
            } 

            catch (Exception e) { 
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString()); 
            } 
        } 

        catch (Exception e) { 

            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The client cannot "guess" the Server's IP. You'll have to do something like service discovery. For example, you could use UDP to broadcast a discovery request from client. The Server would listen on a specific UDP port and answer with its own public IP address (and maybe some other info like api version etc). Then you can setup the client's TCP subsystem with that IP. But that's only one (simplified) example. You may want to google "service discovery". If the Server has one specific dedicated port, you could also scan the network and try that port until client gets a valid answer.

Comment: The server has one spesific dedicated port, but my client is a device which has a connection on wireless. When I scan networks, just find networks with cable not on wifi. Can you give an example for me?

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference between the network on cable and wifi. Why are you sending the IP of the server to the server?

Comment: I don't send my server to the server. I'm trying to find IP of server in client side to connect to server.